# Populate choice list based on being in at least one of multiple user-selected options

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a dashboard that populates a table based on several variables. The most relevant of which are 3 increasingly specific lists.

-Model Suite

-Case Selection Method

-Subwork Program

The user can select multiple instances of each list to aggregate and filter in or out different options. I would like to simplify this and make certain dependencies more clear by removing all 'null' options which would filter out every single entry.
For instance Case Selection X is only ever in a row with Model Suite 1, so if Model Suite 1 is not selected Case Selection X should not be a valid option to select.

In order to do this I have created a code which should filter properly...if I knew the correct syntax.

```
observeEvent(
    input$MdlSte
    ,updateSelectInput(session ,"cseSel" ,"Case Selection Method"
                      ,choices = unique(Rpt.Dat$caseSelectionMethod[Rpt.Dat$modelSuite IN (input$MdlSte)])
                      )
  )
```

input$MdlSte is a simple multi-select list containing the Model Suites selected by the User

I need a method to compare the Rpt.Dat$modelSuite with the list of input$MdlSte. Simply doing an == throws an error due to comparing a single variable with a group. IN throws an unexpected token.

I've used this type of code before (with an == sign) to compare against single values before perfectly fine, but I'm unaware of the syntax to find a value in a list.

Comment: I think you are looking for `%in%` (see `help("%in%")`)

Comment: You might want to check the [selectizeGroup-module](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/selectizeGroup-module.html) from library(shinyWidgets).

Comment: Thank you Bas, that worked.